# How to dynamically schedule multiple tasks in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, scheduling, job-scheduling

I want to dynamically schedule a task based on the user input in a given popup.
The user should be able to schedule multiple tasks and each tasks should be a repeteable task.

I have tried to follow some of the possibilities offered by spring boot using espmale below:

- example 1: https://riteshshergill.medium.com/dynamic-task-scheduling-with-spring-boot-6197e66fec42
- example 2: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-task-scheduler#threadpooltaskscheduler

The Idea of example 1 is to  send a http post request that should then invoke a schudeled task as below :[image]

Each http call will lead to console print as below :
[image]
But I still not able to reach the needed behaviour; what I get as result is the **task1** executed when invoked by **action1** but as soon as a **task2** is executed by an **action2** the first **task1** will stop executing .
Any idea how the needed logic could be implemented?

Comment: We need to see your code so that we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Example 1 demonstrates how to schedule a task based on requested rest api and Example 2 shows how to create ThreadPoolTaskScheduler **for *TaskScheduler***. But you miss an important point, here. Even if you created thread pool, *TaskScheduler* is not aware of that and thus, it needs to be configured so that it can use thread pool. For that, use *SchedulingConfigurer* interface. Here is an example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class TaskConfigurer implements SchedulingConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
    //Create your ThreadPoolTaskScheduler here.
  }
}
```

After creating such configuration class, everything should work fine.